# Is it possible to add handler for chakra.dll JavaScript engine in IIS?

Tags: javascript, iis

Can anyone say if it is possible to add a handler for a newer JavaScript-engine (such as chakra.dll) in IIS 7+ for example the same way as it is done for Python or PHP in IIS (see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/handlers/ and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/configure-web-apps-for-iis-windows?view=vs-2019)?

Comment: 1. Microsoft gave up Chakra based browsers, so it is rather risky to build anything upon it if you don't plan to modify its source code on your own. 2. Microsoft stopped supporting Python/PHP on Windows on Azure App Service. 3. IISNode is not updated recently. So in short, switch to Linux/Node.JS if you want to write JavaScript based server side apps.

Comment: Ok, I actually am aware of this at least partly, but still I am interested in knowing if it is possible, and if so, how, to add modern javascript support in IIS 7+. Anyone any concrete ideas?

Comment: As far as I know, this is impossible.